# Top-Down Racing Game C++

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I'm creating a Top-Down Racing Game in C++ using [GLUT/OPENGL](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) and [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) first of all I just wanted some opinions on how the track should be done. I was thinking about using a tile-map and so far I've implemented one but it draws a polygon for each value in the tile-map then uses the assigned texture. This is obviously a really in efficient way of drawing the background.

So how to go about concatenating the appropriate texture's together into one PNG/GL-TEXTURE that way I can just draw one big polygon and use the texture created from the concatenation process.

Also what's the best way of going about collision detection when it comes to tile-maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few thousand polygons on screen, so what? Do you experience performance issues on anything better than a 5 year old cheap laptop? Cause you shouldn't, and if you do it's not because you use a few thousand polygons.

Comment: 1. 5+ year old computers are common. 2. If the OP is targeting older computers, the optimisation he suggests is sensible, and one that I have made myself. One screen-size polygon is significantly faster than one-polygon-per-tile on graphics hardware of that era.

Comment: For the majority of computers unable to handle this scenario it wouldn't be the poly count that cause problems unless we are talking about some seriously tiny tiles. 5 years is just what I feel comfortable claiming without risking that some nitpicker find an obscure counter-example. As for supporting old hardware incompatibility between the library and old hardware/driver stacks is probably a way bigger issue. But if you seriously think this detour is a good idea write so in an answer and prepare to get downvoted.

Comment: It's just it would be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: @SyntheCypher Not really, the theoretical gain is negligible. You would however increase load time and use a lot more video memory. Depending on the amount, that extra memory requirement could be what breaks the game on some old computers.